# Setting up sqlite with java (import org.sqlite.SQLite cannot be resolved)

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I'm getting the error

> The import org.sqlite cannot be resolved.

This is my first time setting up sqlite with java in eclipse. I did add the `sqlite.jar` file by right clicking the `project>properties` and clicking `Add External Jar`. But I am not sure what is going on with the import error. The import error is coming from the class Personnel.

```
package frontend;

import org.sqlite.SQLite;
import backend.SQLiteDb;
import business.Person;

public class Personnel {
static SQLiteDb db;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     db = new SQLiteDb();
     //db.createPersonnelTable();
    Person person = new Person("Jason", 22, "2123 North St.", 66000.0);
    db.addPerson(person);



    }

}
```

Comment: Is the dependency in your pom.xml?  If not, then add it.  Then to do a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Add External Jar should resolve it. But give it a try to clean build. if it does not resolve the issue,make sure  entry of sqlite.jar exist on .class path file

Comment: I added the external jar already and I did build all. Also my class path says                                                                                          try {
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:sqlite:Andy.SQLite");

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();

  }

Comment: try adding the jar directly under your project/lib folder

Comment: Do you mean in the JRE System Library folder in this image because it won't let me drag and drop it. http://postimg.org/image/vlj39j5d1/

Comment: not inside jre but there will be lib folder inside your project in your workspace

Comment: Isn't that where I right click the project go to properties>java build path> and libraries?? I clicked Add External Jar and chose sqlite.jar? Is this not right?